# apt: no release file [ubuntu jammy]

Tags: ros, ros2, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please find below the error I am getting...

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease

Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414948/apt:-no-release-file-%5Bubuntu-jammy%5D/) by [saintofinternet](https://answers.ros.org/users/147435/saintofinternet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this:

> ```
> E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
> ```

it looks like you're trying to use the ROS 1 package repositories on Ubuntu Jammy.

The ROS 2 package repository would be `http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu` (note the `ros2` in the URL).

ROS 1 does not support Ubuntu Jammy, so the `apt` error is correct: there is no release file it can download.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0